# SSH cannot pass specific commands to the remote router

Tags: ssh

I am trying to run the command "iwlist wlan0 scan" on a remote router in my network. I have tried the following SSH commands

```
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 iwlist wlan0 scan
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 "iwlist wlan0 scan"
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 `iwlist wlan0 scan
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 \`iwlist wlan0 scan\`
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 \"iwlist wlan0 scan\"*
```

but all of these commands lead to the following error:

```
ash: iwlist: not found
```

However when I am actually logging into the router using the command

```
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162
```

and I run "iwlist wlan0 scan" it works and I can see the list of surrounding access points. This means that "iwlist" is actually available on my router but I cannot pass it to the router correctly. Also when I run the following commands

```
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 ls
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 pwd 
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 uname -n
```

They work perfectly fine while if I run

```
ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 route -n
```

it does not work but again if I log into the router and run "route -n" I will get the result. So I guess SSH is choosing which one of my commands to pass and which one not to pass. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have the same environment variables (e.g. PATH) set when you log in, vs. running a command without logging in.

Try the following: find out where the commands are. You may be able to run `which route`, if you're lucky (depending on how much of unix is on the router).

Once you find the full path of the command, try specifying that. For example, if `which route` shows `/sbin/route`, then try replacing `route` in your command with `/sbin/route` - e.g. `ssh -o IdentityFile=~/Dropbox/ALI/id_rsa -l root 172.20.125.162 /sbin/route -n`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was able to fix the problem with your help.